# Bing Maps / JavaScript - trying to open InfoBox with the PushPin click event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bing-maps

I am experimenting with the sample code on the Bing SDK site but am unable to get the click event to work with the pushpins I am adding in a JS .each loop that pulls in longitude, latitude coordinates from a sql server. I can get the push pins to display fine, I can get the InfoBoxes to display fine if I set their visible to true in the loop, but if I set the visible property to false in the loop and then try to set visible to true with the pushpin click event nothing happens. Please advise, thank you.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function () {

        var map = null;
        var pinInfobox = null;

        function LoadMap() {
            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {credentials: "Aq85qFzkJkdfauSc1nXq3IATrqgPGN77_MBhghypyJ94ygTElWHSHYv3WXYZT-3E"} );
        }

        function displayInfobox(e) {
            defaultInfobox.setOptions({ visible: true });
        }

        LoadMap();

        var url = "/Job/GetLocations";
        $.getJSON(url, null, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, LocationData) {
                var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(map.getCenter(), { text: '' });                                  
                pushpin.setLocation(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(LocationData.Latitude, LocationData.Longitude));               

                var Route = LocationData.PickupCity + ' to ' + LocationData.DeliveryCity;
                var Details = 'Pays $' + LocationData.Payment + '<br>' + 'Pickup ' + LocationData.PickupHour + LocationData.PickupMinute + '<br>' + 'Deliver ' + LocationData.DeliveryHour + LocationData.DeliveryMinute;;
                var Content = '<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>';
                var infoboxOptions = { title: Route, description: Details, htmlContent: Content };
                var defaultInfobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(LocationData.Latitude, LocationData.Longitude), infoboxOptions);                    
                Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pushpin, 'click', displayInfobox);
                map.entities.push(pushpin);
                map.entities.push(defaultInfobox);                                     

            });
            map.setView({ zoom: 7, center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(34.470639154314995, -118.55275198817253) });
        });

      });

  </script>
```

Comment: the problem was that I was not using collections for the pins and infoboxes.  like this:     var infoboxLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
    var pinLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that I was not using collections for the pins and infoboxes.

```
var infoboxLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
var pinLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
```